# Change Laravel belongsToMany() returned data format

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm using `belongsToMany()` in my Laravel model and i need to change the function return format.

```
public function platform_information(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        PlatformInformation::class,
        'platform_information_artist',
        'artist_id',
        'platform_information_id')->withPivot([
            'date', 'value'
        ]);
}
```

When I call the function

```
$artist->platform_information()
    ->orderBy('platform_information_id', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
    ->get()
```

Returns the following data:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "platform": "spotify",
            "information": "monthly_listeners",
            "description": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "artist_id": 1,
                "platform_information_id": 1,
                "date": "2022-11-09",
                "value": 55400500
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "platform": "spotify",
            "information": "monthly_listeners",
            "description": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "artist_id": 1,
                "platform_information_id": 1,
                "date": "2022-11-10",
                "value": 55395190
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "platform": "spotify",
            "information": "followers",
            "description": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "artist_id": 1,
                "platform_information_id": 2,
                "date": "2022-11-09",
                "value": 25390584
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "platform": "spotify",
            "information": "followers",
            "description": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "artist_id": 1,
                "platform_information_id": 2,
                "date": "2022-11-10",
                "value": 25410584
            }
        }
    ]
```

The data obtained are correct, but not in the format in which I need them.
This is the format that i need:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "platform": "spotify",
    "information": "monthly_listeners",
    "data" : [
      {
        "artist_id": 1,
        "platform_information_id": 1,
        "date": "2022-11-09",
        "value": 55400500
      },
      {
        "artist_id": 1,
        "platform_information_id": 1,
        "date": "2022-11-10",
        "value": 55395190
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "platform": "spotify",
    "information": "followers",
    "data" : [
      {
        "artist_id": 1,
        "platform_information_id": 2,
        "date": "2022-11-09",
        "value": 25390584
      },
      {
        "artist_id": 1,
        "platform_information_id": 2,
        "date": "2022-11-10",
        "value": 25410584
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do this using the `belongsToMany()` function directly?

Or do I have to do it manually in the controller?

Comment: I would suggest manipulating the response in the controller and let the relationship do what it does now, as it could become very inconvenient if you change the return of a "standard" relationship

Comment: Is there no possibility to do it directly from the function, since this query will yield many results, and I think it will not be optimal to do it manually in the controller if it can be done directly from the function.

Comment: I wouldn't do it in that function, but in a different function in the model if you don't want to do it in the controller. The fact that it results in a large amount of data is kind of a different discussion I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I had not tested it but what I have get from the question, it should work.
I am assuming that you have a model Artist in your Models directory.

```
$artist = \App\Models\Artist::with('platform_information')->get();
```

Then you can dd() to verify the format

```
dd($artist->toArray());
```